# Valor mínimo do input date deve ser o dia de hoje

Tags: html, angular, data

Tenho um input do tipo data, e preciso que não seja possível selecionar data que não seja de hoje para trás, tentei dessa maneira, mas não tive muito sucesso:

HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="atv.dataini" type="date" class="form-control" #one min="{{this.today}}">
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
today = this.dNow.getFullYear() + '-0' + (this.dNow.getMonth() + 1) + '-0' + this.dNow.getDate();
```

também tentei dessa maneira:

HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="atv.dataini" type="date" class="form-control" #one min="{{this.tdNow}}">
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
dNow = this.formatDate(new Date());

formatDate(date) {
    let result = date.split('-').reverse().join('/');
    return result
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma maneira simples é você capturar esses dados no model atv.dataini e dai verifica-los, comparando com a data de hoje e se não for o desejado levantar um erro para o usuario